# PHP, Zend Framework quickstart tutorial: How does this work?

Tags: php, zend-framework

[Here is a link to the tutorial that I am referring to.](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-a-model-and-database-table)

This seems strange to me...in the view script we have this code:

```
<?php echo $this->escape($entry->email) ?>
```

This displays the email address that has been set in the Guestbook model. But the property on the model is `$_email` and it is protected. We're not calling `$entry->getEmail();` so I don't understand how this is working or where it is pulling this information. I know that it works, but I just don't understand how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no property called `$email`, and there is a `__get` magic-method in the class, you are going through that one.

Indeed, quoting the page you linked to :

> `__get()` and `__set()` will provide a
>   convenience mechanism for us to access
>   the individual entry properties, and
>   proxy to the other getters and
>   setters. They also will help ensure
>   that only properties we whitelist will
>   be available in the object.

To learn more about magic methods in PHP 5, you can read [this page of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) -- magic methods are used quite a lot in Zend Framework ; and in other modern Frameworks too, should I add.

Answer (score 1):

The method gets called when an undefined attribute is accessed on a class.

```
public function __get($name)
{
    $method = 'get' . $name;
    if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid guestbook property');
    }
    return $this->$method();
}
```

The method in turn redirects to another method. In this case getEmail().

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a [`__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) method within the $entry object which allows normally inaccessible properties to be accessed.